# Better odds with $9 bucks on lotto?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, odds

I think I have a juicy one! My state's lotto game is 2 dollars, you select 6 numbers between 1 and 40, (odds to get all 6 are 1 in 3,838,380). However, if you pay an extra 1 dollar (so 3 in total) you get a second "Bonus" chance to win, meaning it's still your original 6 numbers that you selected, but they do a second "Bonus" drawing. So to clarify, it's 3 bucks, one set of 6 numbers you've selected, but two drawings on the same day/time.

Now, Let's say you have 9 big ones in cash and you want to put it all on a single game night.

So if your goal is to get a match of all 6, do you have better odds buying 3 "Bonus" tickets at 3 bucks each or is it better to buy four standard tickets at 2 dollars each.

The real question: are the odds better if you have 3 sets of 6 numbers and 2 drawings, or 4 sets of numbers against a single drawing??

Thanks in advance!!!

Sincerely, Hopeful Financial Planner

Comment: Surely one does not win the same jackpot if they match on drawing 2.

Comment: Odds are only half the picture: what are the payouts?  In particular, is it possible for (a) nobody to win; (b) the first drawing to win but not the second; (c) nobody to win in the first drawing but somebody to win in the second?  And if there are winners in both drawings, are both awarded the same amount or is the prize split?  What happens when there are multiple winners (or is that not possible)?

Comment: Thanks for replying!  The question is solely related to best odds of gettng all 6 numbers to match (regardless of actual payout).  Are you more likely to get a full match playing 3 sets of 6 numbers on 2 draws, or 4 sets of 6 numbers on a single draw. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The events are so unlikely that they are almost independent. Therefore a good approximation is to sum the probabilities. Since $2 \cdot 3 > 4$ it is $3/2$ times better to spend 9 than 8 and it would require 12 dollars to match the probability obtained with the bonus.

> The probability of any given number is
>  $p = \binom{6}{40}$
>  The probability that a second number wins depends on if there is any overlap. No overlap maximizes the probability so let's assume that.
>  $$ P(\texttt{win_2}) = P(\texttt{win_2}\mid \texttt{win_1}^*)P(\texttt{win_1}^*) + 0 = p\cdot(1-p)$$
>  which generalizes to $p(j) = p\cdot(1-p)^j = p + \mathcal{O}(p^2)$.
>  I.e.
>  $$ p(x) = P(\texttt{win}) = P(\cup_j^x \texttt{win_j}) = x p +\mathcal{O}(xp^2)$$
>  The probability of winning in any of y draws is $1-(1-p(x))^y$ and the probability of winning in two with 3 tries in each is:
>  $$1 - (1-p(3))^2 = 1 - (1 - 2\cdot p(3) + \mathcal{O}(p^2)) =2\cdot 3 \cdot p +\mathcal{O}(p^2) > 4\cdot p+\mathcal{O}(p^2) = p(4).$$
>  So, the probability is $\frac{3}{2}$ times larger of winning and you would need to spend 12 dollars to get a similar probability.

Comment: Thank you, that's excellent and elegant. :-)

Comment: The use of the spoiler tag seem inappropriate.